# HTML: Select Option styling not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a select box, changing all of the color options to red. However, when I load the webpage the select box still has color black. Any help please?

Here is the HTML & CSS:

```css
select.selector option {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select style="font-size: 16px; padding: 4px;" name="category" id="categoryselector" class="selector">
  <option disabled></option>
  <option value='all'>all</option>
  <option disabled></option>
  <option>Hardware and OS</option>
</select>
```

And here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jxcwnk05/2/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're applying the color to the options within the select box.  To apply it to the visible select box, use:

```
select.selector{
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Select option styling doesn't work in **Chrome (MAC OS X)**, but it will work in Firefox on all systems as well as Chrome (Windows 7).

You can check the detailed description here: [Dealing with the select nightmare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms#Dealing_with_the_select_nightmare)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this code:

```
select option {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color:red;
}
```